# Paypal revise subscription REST not sending approval link in response

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to change plan for the PayPal Subscription. PayPal documnetaion says after sending revision request we get approval link but in my case i am getting all the links but not the apporval and I can't change plan for the subscription without approval link. I am using PayPal REST api.

Paypal Request -
[image]

PayPal Response -

```
    {
    "plan_id": "P-4EH502151X386784AL66RUCY",
    "plan_overridden": false,
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3C187NVB1M5T",
            "rel": "edit",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3C187NVB1M5T",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3C187NVB1M5T/cancel",
            "rel": "cancel",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3C187NVB1M5T/suspend",
            "rel": "suspend",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3C187NVB1M5T/capture",
            "rel": "capture",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this @JTouchLogic ?

Comment: @KevinDanikowski I am cancelling the old subscription and issuing the new one for plan change.